# How to send mail within a servlet using threads or executor service?

Tags: java, servlets, java-threads

I want to send mail based on if a condition

ServletMail.java

```
//somecodes

//this code should code should be executed in background(by threads or something)

if(cond1){

sendmail(firstcond)

}

else{

sendmail(secondcond)

}

//requestdispatcher
```

Comment: This site is for narrowly-focused questions on a specific technical issue. This is much too broad. Servlet, mail, and executors have been covered in many other questions and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadNumber);` . There threadNumber is concurrent use threads.

1. If you use IOC then you can declaration bean
2. Second way simple **executorService** declaration how static variable;

> You can use it like this

```
   if(cond1){
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sendmail(firstcond);
            }
        });
    } else{
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sendmail(secondcond);
            }
        });
    }
```

Do not forget put this `executorService.shutdown();` to web server shutdown listener.

Comment: Can this snippet be used within servlet?

Comment: Ofcourse! Above servlet declare  public static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadNumber); after it is you can use it.

Comment: thanku that worked for me

Comment: welcome! Good luck